# Everything is a set in ZF？

Tags: elementary-set-theory, algebraic-geometry, set-theory

If we accept the Zermelo-Fraenkel system of axioms for set theory, then everything is a set?

In Gabber's *Foundations For Almost Ring Theory*, the author says that accepting the Zermelo-Fraenkel system of axioms for set theory, then everything is a set, and there is no primitive notion of class.

However, after doing some search online, I found that in ZF, one can indeed define a class informally. And I also note that in this book, Grothendieck universe is in use such that for every set $S$, there exists a universe $V$ such that $S \in V$.

Comment: Grothendieck universe is also a set.

Comment: @Hanul Jeon: Well, I notice that. But my question is whether everything a set in ZF?

Comment: Yes. I will post my answer soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one-line answer should be: yes, every object in $\mathsf{ZF}$ is a set.

The core idea of the set theory is that we can code almost all mathematics using sets. It is like that we can encode most daily data (like text, pictures, music, etc) into binary data, although binary data itself is not, for example, a picture or music itself. Thus set theories (like $\mathsf{ZF}$) do not need to consider other objects like bananas and cows.

However, it is sometimes convenient to consider collections of sets that are not sets. (The most reason why they cannot be a set is they are too large to be a set.) This is the reason why we introduce classes. Still, $\mathsf{ZF}$ does not have classes as its primitive notion, so we should deem them syntactic sugar.

It does not mean classes always remain as an informal notion. Some second-order set theories like von Neumann-Gödel-Bernays set theory $\mathsf{NBG}$ or Morse-Kelley set theory $\mathsf{MK}$ take classes as a basic notion. Especially, $\mathsf{NBG}$ is a [conservative extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_extension) of $\mathsf{ZF}$, so we may safely use $\mathsf{NBG}$ in place of $\mathsf{ZF}$.

You mentioned [Grothendieck universes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe) in the last line of your question: they are also sets, although their name contains the word 'universe.' Grothendieck universes are sets that are closed under certain operations (pairing, power set, and indexed union), so they behave like a *small* universe of sets. In fact, Grothendieck universes satisfy all axioms of $\mathsf{ZF}$, and even more, it satisfies second-order $\mathsf{ZF}$!

Comment: So after announcing every set belongs to a universe, we can avoid the notion of proper classes?

Comment: @ToneyLeung There is some subtlety: we do not announce every set belongs to a universe. Rather than that, the universe $V$ is, a fortiori, the collection of all sets since everything is already a set.

Comment: $\mathsf{ZF}$ formally thinks there is no proper class: everything in its domain is a set, and class is another way to call formulas of set theory. However, it is sometimes useful to think of formulas as collections of sets, and it is the reason why we employ the notion of classes.

Comment: OK! I have one more confusion. Why the colletions of sets are too large to be sets? Isn't it  contradictory to everything being a set?

Comment: @ToneyLeung The collection of all sets $V$, or the collection of all ordinals are examples.

Comment: I think you mean "syntactic sugar", not "synthetic sugar" (aspartame and friends?).

Comment: @ZhenLin It was a silly typo, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An excellent article is Shulman's [Set theory for category theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1279), it answers your questions (and much more).